When opening /root/ it prompts me twice for my password
So when I click on /root/ to open and explore it, it asks me for my password (which is normal,) so I type my password and hit enter. It asks me a second time for my password. And this time when I type it and press enter it allows me in the folder.
Why does it do this... every... single... time

Based on this thread, "...I always get 2 password prompts - one for "gvfsd-admin daemon", the other to "perform file operations".
